# Dynamically add fields to type and iterate over them in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm building a dynamic formatting system and I want to allow "automatic" (by TS) fields definition.

I want to obtain, if possible, something like this:

```
enum ContentFormat {
    Markdown = 'md',
    Text = 'txt',
}

type FormattableContent<P extends keyof any> = // ...

type Post = FormattableContent<'body' | 'anotherField'>;
// should expand to:
type Post = {
    body: string;
    bodyOutput: string;
    anotherField: string;
    anotherFieldOutput: string;
    format: ContentFormat;
}
```

This is what I came up:

```
// enum ContentFormat as above
type FormattableFields<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in K]: string;
};
type FormattableOutputFields<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in K as `${string & P}Output`]: string;
};

type FormattableContent<T, K extends keyof T> = FormattableFields<T, K> & FormattableOutputFields<T, K> & {
    format: ContentFormat;
};
```

I'm stuck generating the final `Post` type and, particularly, to define a method that automatically formats all formattable fields, something like this:

```
export const formatContent = async <T, K extends keyof T>(content: FormattableContent<T, K>, fields: K) {
    for (const k of fields) { // here fields is not iterable
        content[`${k}Output`] = doSomething(content[k]);
    }
}
```

Ideally K should be inferred automatically.

Is this at all possible? If yes, how can I write the types?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are trying to iterate over the fields of the content object, what is the need for the second parameter `fields`?

Comment: @kelly you are right, ideally I would iterate directly over all K fields, but I don't know how to iterate over type information, so I added that parameter..

Comment: But you don't *need* to iterate over the type information. You *have* the fields! It's in the `content` object.

Comment: @kelly but I need to discriminate "formattable" input fields from the other fields, no? Like the `format` field or any field that could be added to the final types?

Comment: Yeah but wouldn't a simple filter do the trick for that? `Object.keys` and then `filter`.

Comment: @kelly how can I discriminate the field pairs (`field` and `fieldOutput`)? The `content` object could contain a number of other fields (other than `format`)

Comment: If it ends with the substring `Output`?

Comment: @kelly I lose all type safety and it's not guaranteed that a field ending with `Output` comes from `FormattableContent`

Comment: Yeah but by definition of `FormattableContent` all keys that end with `Output` are going to be inferred as the given inputs, and there's no way to do the reverse (inferring the output keys by inferring the inputs first).